# Choco-solver IntVar declaration : How to declare an IntVar with two(or more) boundedDomain?

Tags: c++, choco

```
IntVar v = model.intVar("v", 1, 12, true);
// or 
v= model.intVar("v", 20, 30, true);
```

I want the value of IntVar v not only in [1,12] but also in [20,30] and in other segment of values [...,....]
I don't understand how to do this with the specific declaration of an IntVar

Comment: Most direct way would be to define a class that acts like a number (has operator +, - *, % and/or can be implicitly converted to a number) but the assignment operator, constructor, and math operators reject out of range values.

Comment: I apologize but don't understand the link of your answer with the specific writing of the Choco-Solver type IntVar declaration

Answer (score 1):

In choco-solver, you can either define bounded domain variables (with `model.intVar(name, lowerBound, upperBound)`)

```java
// domain is [1,7]
IntVar v = model.intVar("v", 1,7);
```

or enumerated domain variables (with `model.intVar(name, values...)`:

```java
// domain is {1,3,5}
IntVar v = model.intVar("v", new int[]{1,3,5});
```

So, if the domain you want to declare is made of ranges, there is no other option than to list all possible values.

```java
// domain is [1,3]U[5,7]
IntVar v = model.intVar("v", new int[]{1,2,3,5,6,7});
```